How to find exact names in windows search (or escape characters)?
A query of "(2)" in windows search (Windows 11) give me this result:


How can I avoid getting 2 (2) as a match here?
Where can I find syntax rules about brackets and more in advanced query syntax?


Try this : ~="(2)".

Per the duplicate ~"*(2)*" should also work - * being a wildcard so the search you are doing is "any characters either side of the exact phrase (2). You could also use ~"*(2).jpg" to search for only files that end with (2).jpg.
